# Run-time error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a run-time error 91 and I have no idea why. I used this code for a different workbook and it works perfectly, the information in the columns are different that I'm extracting but I changed all the columns and ranges to the correct one, but now I'm getting this error here and the only difference is the Range, please help!

```
Range(Cells(20, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("C2").Select
```

That is the beginning but here is where the error occurs:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(msheet).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("A20:A" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Please help, I don't know what I'm missing. Thanks!

Here is the beginning of the code:

```
Sub getdata()
Dim mastername As String
Dim count As Long
Dim match As Long
Dim repeat As Long
Dim path As String
Dim status As String
Dim name As String
Dim mpath As String
Dim cpath As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim mbank As String
Dim mname As String

mpath = Sheets("Master log").Cells(14, "W").Value
mname = Sheets("Master log").Cells(15, "W").Value
msheet = Sheets("Master log").Cells(16, "W").Value
Sheets("MGPR1").Range("A1:AA50000").ClearContents

name = Application.ActiveWorkbook.name
cpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"

Windows(name).Activate

'--open Management report  workbook if not already open
If CheckFileIsOpen(mname) = False Then
Workbooks.Open mpath & mname
End If
'-------------------------------------------

Windows(mname).Activate
    Sheets(msheet).Select

    'select full data

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
       ' LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       LastCol = 20
    End With
```

Comment: Needs some more detail.  Your first bit of code looks like it is sorting a large range, but your second bit of code is only sorting column A.  Also, what is `msheet`?  Is it a variable you have defined?  If it is the name of a sheet then use `Sheets("msheet")`

Comment: Based on the error I assume it has something to do with your lack of quotes around `msheet`.

Comment: Dim s As Worksheet
Set s = Worksheets(1) ... msheet could be index?

Comment: I added the additional information. msheet is referenced correctly. The code is partially working. It's opening the other workbook, going to the correct worksheet of that workbook (which is msheet) but once in that workbook/worksheet it's getting the error and I'm going to assume that it has to do with the sorting just because nothing else seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

you have to reference the sheet of the `range("A20.....")` or else its in activesheet.

Something like `sh.range("...")` , or use a `with` section like this example:

```
with ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(msheet)
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:= .Range("A20:A" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
end with
```

also to help referencing, and stop using activate/select :

```
 Dim Wb as Workbook
 Dim Sh as Worksheet

 'other code, i just write the needed code now
 set wb = Workbooks.Open mpath & mname
 set Sh = wb.Sheets(msheet)

 with Sh

     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     'lots of stuff to do (....) please wait , computing .... error / no really i try to be serious here!
 end with
```

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the error is:

> 91 - Object variable not set

It is obtuse the chain of objects involved. This is a Recorded Macro that does the type of thing you are trying to do. If in doubt unwind a complex statement into simplier ones.

Also always do a `Msgbox Vartype(whatever):Msgbox IsEmpty(whatever):msgbox IsNull(whatever)`. This allows you to check assumptions on what something is.

```
Range("A1:G19").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>sub", Operator:=xlAnd
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Range("H34").Select
```

Comment: She wasn't asking what the error means.  She was asking how to fix her code.

Comment: That isn't true.  The question implies that the meaning of Error 91 is not known.  This is an answer, though it could be more complete.

Comment: You're right. I did leave out the assigned variable, I probably should have added that. I added the beginning of the code to the top. I know the error means object variable not set, but I feel like it is. Obviously I may be wrong.

Comment: use `with` ; stop using `select`. that's why the error of this post occured in the first place !

Comment: @noodlesstillalive, where would I enter that on my code? Not the message box but the code you wrote under it. If you would like to see the workbook with the whole code it's on this forum: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?51160-run-time-error-91

Comment: Excel wrote that code not me. I created a dummy data set. Turned on recording, turned AutoFilter on, set a filter, then sorted. Turned off recording. AFAICT sort is not a legal property or method of autofilter. Recording is **Alt + T, M, R**. The macro will be in a new module in the VBA editor.